# Prove $[A,B^n] = nB^{n-1}[A,B]$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I am trying to show that $[A,B^n] = nB^{n-1}[A,B]$ where A and B are two Hermitian operators that commute with their commutator. However, I am running into a little problem and would like a hint of how to proceed.

If A and B commute then $[A,B] = ABA^{-1}B^{-1} = e$ where `e` is the identity element of the group.

$$\therefore AB=BA$$

$$n=1; [A,B^1] = (1)B^0[A,B] = e$$
This statement is certainly true. however moving on to $n = 2$ I find...

$$[A,B^2] = AB^2A^{-1}B^{-2} = ABBA^{-1}B^{-1}B^{-1} = BBAA^{-1}B^{-1}B^{-1}$$

Where in the last step I have used the fact that A and B commute to rearange the terms. However, it is plain to see that this last term simply reduces to the identity as well and for the `n = 2` case we have:

$$[A,B^2] = e \ne 2B[A,B] = 2Be = 2B$$

Clearly I have assumed something I shouldn't have. The fact that there is a multiplicative factor of `n` implies I should be adding things, but I thought if I kept it as general as possible, the answer should just fall out naturally. I don't want an answer please, only guidance.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't $[A,B] = AB - BA$?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems that the question (v1) is caused by the fact that there are two different notions of the [commutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator):

1. One for [group theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Group_theory): 
   $$\tag{1} [A,B] ~:=~ ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$$ 
   (or sometimes $[A,B] := A^{-1}B^{-1}AB$, depending on convention), which is relatively seldom used in physics.
2. One for [rings/associative algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Ring_theory): 
   $$\tag{2} [A,B]:=AB-BA,$$ 
   which is the definition usually used in physics. (This latter definition (2) generalizes to a [supercommutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercommutator) in [superalgebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superalgebra).)

The identity

$$\tag{*}  [A,B^n] ~=~ nB^{n-1}[A,B]$$

holds in the latter sense (2), if $[[A,B],B]=0$. (It is not necessary to demand $[A,[A,B]]=0$.) More generally, for a sufficiently well-behaved function $f$, we have

$$\tag{**} [A,f(B)] ~=~ f^{\prime}(B)[A,B], $$

if $[[A,B],B]=0$.

The group commutator (1) is dimensionless, which (among other things) makes the identity (*) unnatural to demand for group commutators.

Comment: I got it, you have to use the identity [A,BC] = [A,B]C + [B,A]C coupled with what you said above. I am so foolish. Thanks!

Comment: if $[A,B]$ doesn't commute with $B$, then does it go before or after $B$?

Comment: Eqs. ($\ast$) & ($\ast\ast$) do generically _not_ hold in either ordering (or even linear combinations thereof) if $[A,B]$ doesn't commute with $B$.

Comment: How to proof [A,f(B)] = f′(B)[A,B]?

Comment: Hi @Basheer Algohi. Is there a class of functions $f$ where you can see how to prove it?

Comment: @Qmechanic, Yes, polynomial p(A^)

Comment: Right, Taylor expansion of $f$ is the basic idea.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way to prove this relationship, by induction:

1. Verify that the statement holds for $n = 1$

$$
[A,B^1]=1 \cdot B^{1-1} [A,B] = [A,B]
$$

2. Show that, if the formula holds for $n=k ~ \big(I\big)$, then it also holds for $n=k+1$, using the identity $[X, YZ] = [X,Y]Z + Y[X,Z] ~\big(II\big)$ and the fact that $B$ commutes with $[A,B] ~\big(III\big)$

$$
\begin{align}
[A,B^{(k+1)}] &= [A,B^k B] \\
& = [A,B^k]B + B^k[A, B] ~\big(II\big)\\
& = k B^{k-1}[A,B]B + B^k[A, B] ~\big(I\big) \\ 
& = k B^{k-1}B[A,B] + B^k[A, B] ~\big(III\big) \\
& = k B^k[A,B] + B^k[A, B] \\
& = (k + 1) B^k[A,B] \\
& = (k + 1) B^{(k+1)-1}[A,B] \\
\end{align}
$$

3. Since both the basis and the inductive step have been performed, by mathematical induction, the statement holds for all natural numbers $n$. $\Box$

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could show this relation in an other way:

$[A,B^n]=[A,B^{n-1}B]=B^{n-1}[A,B]+[A,B^{n-1}]B=...$

Then you take $[A,B^{n-1}]B$ and repeat the process:

$[A,B^{n-1}]B=[A,B^{n-2}B]B=B^{n-2}[A,B]B+[A,B^{n-2}]BB$

So $B$ commute with $[A,B]$

$[A,B^{n-1}]B=B^{n-1}[A,B]+[A,B^{n-2}]B^2$

Repeat for $n$ steps

$[A,B^n]=B^{n-1}[A,B]+B^{n-1}[A,B]+...+B^{n-1}[A,B]=nB^{n-1}[A,B]$