# How does the following commutator for measured observables and this operator relation imply the following relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

$$
\hat{\Omega}_j{(\tilde{q}_j)}=\Omega_j(\tilde{q}_j-\hat{q}_j)
$$

$$
[\hat{q}_j,\hat{q}_l]=ik_{jl}
$$

Implies

$$
[\hat{q}_j,\hat{\Omega}_l]= \frac{\partial\Omega_l(\tilde{q}_l-\hat{q}_l)}{\partial\hat{q}_l}.ik_{jl}
$$

Comment: Can you clarify what are the symbols in your questions?

Comment: The hats refer to arbitrary operators, and the tilde the measured observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints to the question (v1):

1. Let $\hat{Z}^I$ be operators that satisfies a [Heisenberg algebra](http://planetmath.org/heisenbergalgebra) 
   $$\tag{1} [\hat{Z}^I,\hat{Z}^J]~=~i\hbar ~\omega^{IJ} ~{\bf 1},$$ 
   where $\omega^{IJ}=-\omega^{JI}$ is an antisymmetric real matrix. The important property will be that the commutators $[\hat{Z}^I,\hat{Z}^J]$ belong to the [center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28algebra%29) of the Heisenberg algebra, i.e. commute with everything.
2. Let $f(\hat{Z})$ and $(\partial_{J}f)(\hat{Z})$ denote the [Weyl-ordered operators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57299/2451) corresponding to the functions/symbols $f(z)$ and 
   $$\tag{2} (\partial_{J}f)(z)~:=~\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial z^J},$$ 
   respectively.
3. Then using e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/57340/2451) formula for the Weyl-ordered operators, it is possible to show$^1$ 
   $$\tag{3} [\hat{Z}^I, f(\hat{Z})]~=~\sum_J [\hat{Z}^I,\hat{Z}^J]~(\partial_{J}f)(\hat{Z}).$$
4. The corresponding classical formula
   $$\tag{4} \{z^I, f(z)\}_{PB}~=~\sum_J \{z^I,z^J\}_{PB}~(\partial_{J}f)(z)$$
   is a consequence of the Poisson property/Leibniz rule for a [Poisson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_algebra) (PB).

--

$^1$ Equation (3) actually also holds for many other operator-orderings.

Comment: Actually after posting this answer, I realized that I have probably misread OP's notation and OP only consider the case where $f(z)$ depends on a single argument, so that no operator ordering issues arise, and the question is much simpler a la [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87038/2451) question. Oh, well, here is the generalization to several variables.