# Why does $\langle p| V(x)|x_{0}\rangle = V(x_{0})\langle p| x_{0}\rangle$ holds?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

If $\hat{p}$ is the position operator, one has:
$$\langle p| \hat{p}|x_{0}\rangle = \overline{\langle x_{0}|\hat{p}|p\rangle} = p \overline{\langle x_{0}|p\rangle} = p \langle p|x_{0}\rangle.$$
And my professor wrote, in its lecture notes, that if the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ is $\hat{H}= \frac{1}{2m}\hat{p} + V(x)$ then:
$$\langle p| \hat{H}|x_{0}\rangle = \left(\frac{1}{2m}p^{2}+V(x_{0})\right)\langle p| x_{0}\rangle$$
Why does it follow that $\langle p|V(x)|x_{0}\rangle = V(x_{0})\langle p|x_{0}\rangle$? How does one prove it?

Comment: Usually $\hat p$ is not a position but rather momentum operator. $\hat x$ is position operator, i.e. $\hat x | x_0 \rangle = x_0 | x_0 \rangle$. Then $V(\hat x) | x_0 \rangle = V(x_0) | x_0 \rangle$

Comment: Your first equation is not correct, unless $\hat{p}$ represents the momentum operator. Actually, the result is still correct of the first equation (but this may be coincidentally...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the definition of a function of an observable, as for example discussed in Dirac's *The Principles of Quantum Mechanics, fourth edition, p. 41-45*:

If $A$ is an observable with $A |a\rangle  = a\, |a\rangle$, then a function $f$ of $A$ is defined through

$$ f(A) |a\rangle = f(a) |a\rangle \quad . $$

Thus, in the case of a single-particle potential $V(X)$, where $X$ denotes the position operator, we find
$$V(X) |x\rangle = V(x)|x\rangle $$
and therefore
$$\langle p|V(X)|x\rangle = V(x) \langle p|x\rangle \quad . $$

Comment: I think one should add that this is only true for analytical functions, since they can be written as a Taylor Series.

Comment: @Jan2103 See for example the comments [in this physics SE post/ answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/87039/232314).

Comment: Additionally, Dirac also notes this 'problem' in his  *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, ed. 4, p. 41, equation 34.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.