# Commutators with function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I have following exercise:
If $[C,D]$ is a c-number and $f(x)$ is a well-behaved function (i.e. all derivatives exist and are finite), show that:
$$[C, f(D)]=[C,D]f'(D)$$
 where $f'(D) = \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

I used expansion:
$$f(D) = \sum_{k} a_k D^k $$
that way:
$$\sum_k a_k [C,D^k]=\sum_k a_k k [C,D]D^{k-1}$$
 I don't know how to show that 
$$[C,D^k]=k[C,D]D^{k-1} $$

Do I need to expand function from operator in another way?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78222/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Yeah. That's enough. Thank you. Shame, that I couldn't find before I posted the question, but I've reach my goal, so that's nice.

Comment: @misimik +1 even though simple and you did work it out, this is a good example of a [derivation at work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28abstract_algebra%29) so it's a pretty example to keep in mind when talking about this stuff (shows how a kind of chain rule comes from Leibnitz rule). The linked example also (which you need to put ladder operators in their normal ordering).