# Calculations with operators - Proof: Equation of Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I have a problem in Quantum mechanics 1 with Operators. I have to prove the following equation. I tried it for about 4 hours without any result:

Condition: $[[\hat A,\hat B],\hat A]=[[\hat A,\hat B],\hat B]=0$

$$
e^{\hat A} \hat B = (\hat B + [\hat A,\hat B]) e^{\hat A}
$$

Info: $e^{\hat A}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\hat A) ^n}{n!}$

Maybe you could help me?

I've done these steps:

$$
[e^{\hat A}, \hat B] = [\hat A,\hat B] e^{\hat A} = e^{\hat A} [\hat A,\hat B] 
$$

$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{(\hat A)^n}{n!} \hat B - \hat B \frac{(\hat A)^n}{n!}\right) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{(\hat A)^n}{n!} \hat A \hat B - \frac{(\hat A)^n}{n!} \hat B  \hat A\right) 
$$

But now I don't know how to go on...

Comment: Perhaps show more work on what you have tried so far. This will help others to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78222/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

$[A^n,B]=n[A,B]A^{n-1}$ (prove by induction)
$[\exp(A),B]=\Sigma\frac{1}{n!}[A^n,B]=\Sigma\frac{1}{n!}n[A,B]A^{n-1}=[A,B]\exp(A)$