# How to interpret $\left[f(A), B\right] = \left[A, B \right]\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ - how to differentiate with respect to an operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differentiation

From [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/98379/212053) and [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/commutator-of-function-of-operators.765633/) I know the commutation relation for two operators are:

$$\left[f(A), B\right] = \left[A, B \right]\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$$
*if* $\left[A, \left[A, B \right]\right] =0$ and $f$ is a reasonably behaved function.

What does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ mean? How can I differentiate with respect to an operator?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78222/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formally, you treat the operator as if it were a variable.

It works because functions of operators are usually defined by their Taylor series. If we plug that into the left side, the problem reduces to calculating $[A^n, B]$ (since the commutator is a linear operation). By repeatedly using $[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$ we find
$$[A^n,B] = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^k[A,B]A^{n-k-1}.$$
Now if $[A,[A,B]]=0$, as you write, we can switch all $A$ to one side and get
$$[A^n,B] = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[A,B]A^{n-1} =[A,B]\,n A^{n-1}$$
which on the right is exactly the usual rule for differentiation with respect to $A$, if $A$ was a variable. So for the purpose of calculating the original commutator, you can just treat it as if it was a variable and derive with respect to it. Careful though whenever $f$ is a function of multiple non-commuting operators.

Comment: So it would be accurate to write it like this:
$$\left[f(\hat A), \hat B\right] = \left[\hat A, \hat B \right]\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$$ yep?

Comment: Well, yes, but if you start making hats I would also write one in the denominator of the derivative.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought that I deliberately miss it out, to indicate that it is treated as variable there, not as an operator.

Comment: If you write the argument of $f$ with a hat you need it in the denominator, otherwise it's inconsistent.